# Process.StandardOutput stops reading

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a process, hide its window and then print its output in my program. I am achieving it with this code:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = path,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Verb = "runas"
     }
};

proc.Start();

while(!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

It works with other programs but for this one it's stopping at some point. My guess is that it sends too much messages, because before actually loading it spams a ton of messages that say: "Initializing... n%". It reads it until it reaches around 90-95% and then stops reading. My guess is that it can't read anymore because it sent too much messages. What can I do to read the whole output?

Comment: do you get some sort of error?

Comment: `My guess is that it can't read anymore because it sent too much messages`  Why would that be your first hypothesis?

Comment: After reader the remarks i think you will be in a deadlock. Try to read it asynchronous or otherwise use the WaitForExit() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You should be reading from standard error as well.

Comment: `Process` doesn't have a stream called `StandartOutput`... can you show your actual code?

Comment: I thought that it's because of the spam of "Initializing" messages because it works perfectly fine with other programs. About WaitForExit(), program isn't exiting immediately after finishing. It is waiting for a key press. My idea was to wait until a specific message was shown and terminate the process. Will reading it asynchronously help though?

Comment: The code I mentioned in the question is the exact code I am using, not sure why you can't see it.

Comment: `StandartOutput` is a typo.  It is not the exact code you are using.  Please show us your actual code.

Comment: Let me double check it... Yup, it was misspelled, thanks for pointing out. Everything else is the same.

Comment: You have to trouble-shoot this by *first* omitting the CreateNoWindow  = true assignment.  So you can see any error messages displayed by the program.  Next you'll have to consider that it might be asking for input.

Comment: I will do that, but I am sure that it doesn't need any input until the end.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev That hypothesis might not be true.  Challenge your assumptions.

Comment: How would I make the process show its window while redirecting the StandardOutput?

Comment: Your test code has some flaws. I suspect the program where you never exit while monitoring standard output does a Write("Finished") instead of WriteLine("Finished"), which would mean that the ReadLine call never reads the "Finished" expected value. Just like if you do a ReadLine from console never finishes until "Enter" is pressed, generating the valuable chr(13)chr(10) sequence. Is the second program under your control - i.e. do you own the source code?  This sounds like a bad way to do inter-process synchronization.

Comment: I used the same source code with a program that behaves similarly. The problem here was that after those "Initialized" messages, it continues writing other stuff and then waits for input. The problem is that I never get to see the messages after "Initialized" ends. I tried to read the lines asynchronously instead of using this code and it worked, but it only read it until "Initialized" messages reached 100% and stopped reading at all.

Comment: So the reason is a combination of waiting for input and writing instead of writeline-ing. Changing to asynchronous read will not solve your issue...

Comment: I was just trying to see if my hypothesis was actually true, which I proved, because the code I provided in the question failed to do what I achieved with asynchrounous reading.

Comment: If you do not control the "target" program, you might want to consider piping the output to a file "proc.exe > out.txt" and "tail" out.txt. You can use something like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7568/Tail-NET, bad code but could get you what you need with some work. What you are looking for will not be trivial to implement and will be a nightmare to maintain since behaviour might be different for different inputs not to mention versions. If you do control the target program, look for things like system wide mutexes, named pipes and inter-process comunication in general.

Comment: Can you try to clarify what your end goal is? Do you want to stop your code program once input is needed?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not that experienced. I was just experimenting. I would really appreciate if you can provide any example code I can try and make to fit my needs. Thank you for the answers though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clarify what it is you want to accomplish, and everyone will be able to help you better. What is it you want to do?

Comment: My goal is to terminate it when a message is sent, because it always sends a specific message when it's done. I actually want to read the lines and based on the process' output to print out a message. My goal wasn't actually to just print out the lines, I want to print out a simple message of the result of the process. That's why I approached it this way, because I thought I can just see if the current line contains something that would help me determine the result of the process.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make a workaround. It turns out the program actually needed input inbetween the initialization and the actual result. Thanks to [@Alexandru Clonțea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8695782/alexandru-clon%C8%9Bea) I decided that I would not run the process, but create a .bat file, which contains the following command:

```
program.exe > output.txt < input.txt
```

Where program.exe is the executable, output.txt is the file that is going to contain the output of the program and input.txt in my case is just an empty text file so I can just get some kind of an input and make the program finish.

Comment: Take note tat for other "cases" in the future for this approach, you might have to actually have multiple lines as input, instead of an empty file. Think of it as mimicking what input is needed from the console.